# Where do I start to look for an automatic off feature on a circuit? (Guidance)

Tags: timer, delay

My child has a light up toy that turns off after 20 minutes and she likes it all night when she’s sleeping. I’m trying to figure out where to start looking among the circuit for the automatic off feature so I can remove it. Is it typically something as simple as a transistor I can short or is there an rtc for the timer? Does anyone know the common practice for light up toy automatic off timers?

Any help or general suggestions would be great as there’s no version that stays on all night for her.

Thanks

Comment: `common practice for light up toy automatic off timers` .... probably is none

Comment: open the toy and try to draw the schematic diagram

Comment: The toy has limited battery life . right. ? How often are willing to change batteries?  Weekly? Every few days? You/she needs a better solution.

Comment: It’s takes  3AA but I soldered a power supply to it so it plugs in and no longer needs batteries.

Comment: Your best bet is to take out any micro-controller/timer inside and connect the lights directly. (Adding a switch if you want).

Comment: It's possible that if you found a way to disable the timer, this might shorten the life of the product if it hasn't been designed to operate continuously. It's even _conceivable_ that running continuously could potentially be dangerous if something were to get too hot. (_Hopefully_, it would have been designed to cope with many, repeated re-activations, but even the most persistent child is unlikely to keep turning it back on for 8-10 hours continuously).

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a reverse engineering, modification, or repair question. Please be aware that such questions must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being discussed, so that you can ask specific, focused questions that can be answered concisely. Otherwise, the question is far too broad. More information can be found here: [Is asking how to fix a faulty circuit on topic?](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/2478/11683).

Answer (score 1):

While it is POSSIBLE that there is identifiable auto-off componentry, it is more likely that it is implemented as a software timer and that it has no identifiable individual components associated with this function.

A solution that has a reasonably good chance of working is to occasionally disconnect the power supply for a brief period. Depending how the toy "wakes up" this may be almost invisible or unacceptable - if it sings, howls, whistles or plays "The Star Spangled Banner" on waking then this is not your solution.
 This feature could be implemented by placing a transistor in a supply lead and operating a timer that occasionally turns the transistor off.
Details on how to do this can be supplied if this is an acceptable solution.

You need to ENSURE that your mains based solution is close to "intrinsically safe' - that at a minium it can not provide enough energy at the toy to cause a fire no matter what. You know that - but it's worth reinforcing.

There are many many 555 based astable timer circuits on web.

[Here](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/TechTip/555-timer-tutorial.html) is a typical tutorial page. See the astable circuit in fig 10. - thus:

Make R1 large and R2 very small. R1 then controls charging and R2 discharging.

[image]
https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/TechTip/555-timer-tutorial-fig11.jpg

The circuit can easily be arranged to drive a transistor - ask if of interest.

A digital timer solution would more easily implement times in the 10+ minute range at equal or lower cost and complexity.

And [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=555+timer&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiMwNGJovLiAhWOfisKHewgCNoQ_AUIECgB&biw=823&bih=404) are images with links to pages for a zillion more.

**____________________________________________**

While it's off the original topic, and while I'm not expert in ANY field of child raising (except by having helped raise two children long ago :-) ) I suspect that it may be preferable to provide a means of easily mechanically re-awakening the toy/light that leaving it on. Fear of the dark and use of night lights are normal, but learning that "dark is good" is also desirable.
Also, various "experts" suggest that deeper darkness is better than sleeping in a lit environment - I don't know the merits of this but note it 'for completeness'.

Comment: @Destreation Off-topic, but for the "dark is good" side of things, from my (very) long-ago childhood, I can recommend [The Owl Who Was Afraid of the Dark](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01JOBLBC6) by Jill Tomlinson.